# Lorentz homogeneous group and observables

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, group-theory, group-representations

For generators of the Lorentz group we have the following algebra:
$$
[\hat {R}_{i}, \hat {R}_{j} ] = -\varepsilon_{ijk}\hat {R}_{k}, \quad [\hat {R}_{i}, \hat {L}_{j} ] = -\varepsilon_{ijk}\hat {L}_{k}, \quad [\hat {L}_{i}, \hat {L}_{j} ] = \varepsilon_{ijk}\hat {R}_{k}. 
$$
For the splitting of algebra, we can introduce operators 
$$
\hat {J}_{k} = \hat {R}_{k} + i\hat {L}_{k}, \quad \hat {K}_{k} = \hat {R}_{k} - i\hat {L}_{k}.
$$ 
So
$$
[\hat {J}_{i}, \hat {J}_{j} ] = -\varepsilon_{ijk}\hat {J}_{k}, \quad [\hat {K}_{i}, \hat {K}_{j} ] = -\varepsilon_{ijk}\hat {K}_{k}, \quad [\hat {J}_{i}, \hat {K}_{j}]  = 0.
$$
So, each irreducible representation of Lie algebra is characterized by $(j_{1}, j_{2})$, where $j_{1}$ is max eigenvalue of $\hat {J}_{3}$ and $j_{2}$ is max eigenvalue of $\hat {K}_{3}$.

Then I can classify objects that transform through the matrices of the irreducible representations,
$$
\Psi_{\mu \nu}' = S^{j_{2}}_{\mu \alpha }S^{j_{2}}_{\nu \beta}\Psi_{\alpha \beta},
$$
where $S^{j_{i}}_{\gamma \delta}: (2j_{i} + 1)\times (2j_{i} + 1)$.

For $(0, 0)$ I have scalar field, for $\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0\right); \left(0; \frac{1}{2}\right)$ I have spinor, for $(1, 0); (0, 1)$ I have 3-vectors $\mathbf a, \mathbf b -> \mathbf a + i\mathbf b$ creating antisymmetrical tensor etc.

Also, for scalar $j_{1} + j_{2} = 0$, for spinor - $\frac{1}{2}$, for tensor - $1$. So, the question: is sum $j_{1} + j_{2}$ experimentally observed? Is it connected with a spin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the comination $j_1 + j_2$ determines the spin of the particle. Note however, that this is an [addition of angular mementum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Tensor_product_space) which may be complicated.

Furthermore, you can count the degrees of freedom:
In $(j_1, j_2)$, each contribute $2j_1 + 1$ states and we construct a tensor product, so $(j_1, j_2)$ gives $(2j_1 + 1) * (2j_2 + 2)$ degrees of freedom. For the vector we have $(1/2, 1/2) \mapsto 2 * 2 = 4$ degrees of freedom.

If the representation is reducible, i.e. of the form $(j_1, j_2) + (k_1, k_2)$, then you simply add the d.o.f. you get from each pair. The dirac spinor has $(1/2, 0) + (0, 1/2) \mapsto (2) + (2) = 4$ degrees of freedom, the field-strength tensor has $(1, 0) + (0, 1) \mapsto 3 + 3 = 6$ d.o.f.

As a sidenote: the representations $(1, 0)$ do **not** corresond to vectorlike degrees of freedom, but rather to antisymmetric self-dual tensors. $(0, 1)$ is the antisymmetric anti-self-dual tensor. The vector (and the only way to get a vector out of this) is $(1/2, 1/2)$!

Comment: But how did you realize that the $j_{1} + j_{2}$ is a spin?

Comment: Maybe, it's refer to the fact, that $j_{1} + j_{2}$ corresponds to some representation of $\frac{1}{2}(\hat {R}_{3} + i\hat {L}_{3}) + \frac{1}{2}(\hat {R}_{3} - i\hat {L}_{3})$, which is rotations generator?

Comment: Indeed. Spin in general (not limited to the S = 1/2 case) is nothing but the representation w.r.t. the rotation group, which is a subgroup of the Lorentz group.

Comment: And we can talk about $j_{1} + j_{2}$ as observable because operator-matrix (as tensor product of two operators $\hat {J}_{i}, \hat {K}_{i}$) of corresponding irreducibles representation is hermite?

Comment: This is a difficult matter, as the $\hat K_i$ themselves are actually not Hermitian. This has to do with the fact that the underlying group's parameter space is non-compact (boosts can go up to any rapidity). The $\hat J_i$ are perfectly observable, though, as is the [Pauli-Lubanski pseudovector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli-Lubanski_pseudovector).

Comment: How did you identity (particularly as observable) $\hat {J}_{i}$ with Pauli-Lubanski vector? The operator of the space part of this vector is proportional to $\hat {\mathbf L} - [\hat {\mathbf R} \times \hat {\mathbf P }]$, so I don't understand. And $\hat {J}_{i}$ isn't Hermitian, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a representation labeled by $(j_1,j_2)$ corresponds to the total spin $j_1+j_2$, (rigourously speaking of spin needs that one of $j_1$ or $j_2$ is zero) and if $j_1=j_2$, this is a real representation, but you may have a representation which is a sum or irreductible representations ,  some examples:

$(\frac{1}{2},0)$ corresponds to a left-handed Weyl spinor

$(0,\frac{1}{2})$ corresponds to a right-handed Weyl spinor

$(\frac{1}{2},0) + (0,\frac{1}{2})$, is the  Dirac bi-spinor

$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ corresponds to a  Lorentz vector.

$(1,0) + (0,1)$, is the  electromagnetic field representation

More generally, if the complex conjugate of a representation (interverting in all terms $j_1$ and $j_2$) is the same as the representation, then the representation is real.

For instance, the Dirac representation, or the electromagnetic field representation, are real representations.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand, how to identity experimentally observed spin and $j_{1} + j_{2}$?

Comment: Good question...Well, I would say, that practically, the observed particles are in a representation $(0,x)$ or $(x,0)$ or a sum $(x,0)+(0,x)$

Comment: So maybe it is abusive to speak of spin if $j_1$ and $j_2$ are both not zero.

Comment: Why? If one of $j_{i}$ is equal to zero, it only means that one of matrices of irreducible representations is absent. Moreover, only a sum of $j_{1}, j_{2}$ may be associated with hermite operator.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you can "observe" only the sum $j_{1} + j_{2}$.

Comment: That is not true. E.g., the $(1/2, 0)$ and $(0, 1/2)$ representations are easily distinguishable due to [partity violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28physics%29#Parity_violation).

Comment: @Neuneck , you commented on my comment, didn't you?